# Каким образом можно заставить Vue преобразовать вручную добавленную вёрстку компонента в объект?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Имеется некий компонент. **SomeComponent**, например. Список из **SomeComponent** генерируется с помощью PHP. Также на странице есть кнопка добавления, но, единственное как она привязана ко Vue, так это через root-элемент. На других страницах эта кнопка ведёт на конкретные страницы добавления. Здесь же есть смысл переопределить поведение с помощью **addEventListener**. Обернуть это в родительский компонент не вариант, т.к. кнопка находится в базовом шаблоне PHP и используется в десятке других представлений. Был вариант просто оборачивать все элементы как новые экземпляры Vue с разными *id*. И этот вариант работает, но происходит потеря связи с **Vuex**.

Comment: я вставляю такие вещи в стиле jsonp. тоесть в json который передается нужномо колбэку. А потом рендери свой компонент как хочется уже средствами vue.

Comment: @eri так дело в том, что отрендерить не проблема. Проблема в том, что вновь созданный объект компонента никак не связан с root, в котором определён Vuex.Store. Он не имеет связи с root, в отличие от тех, за которыми Vue начал следить сразу после загрузки страницы. Это даже можно наглядно посмотреть во Vue DevTools. В списке объектов вновь добавленный экземпляр просто не отображается, хотя рендерится нормально.

Comment: Вы бы хоть какой-то код добавили, а то я себе представил такое: `<button id="root" ...>Кнопка</button>`